# Create different pickle files iterating a list of DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I'm trying to write a function that will write pickle files from a list containing DataFrames. I want to iterate through that list and create a different pickle file, with a different file name, from each DataFrame. I've written this function:

```
def picklecreator(dflist):
a=1
for b in dflist:
    b.to_pickle('filename_' + str(a) + '.pkl')
    a=+1

return 1
```

This function only creates the first pickle file 'filename_1.pkl' How can I make it to work for all the DataFrames in my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
def picklecreator(dflist):
    for i, b in enumerate(dflist):
        b.to_pickle(r'd:/temp/filename_{:02d}.pkl'.format(i+1))
    return 1
```

But i would use HDF store instead - it's much more flexible and more convenient.

Demo:

```
def save_dflist_hdfs(dflist, file_name_ptrn='d:/temp/data_{:02}.h5', **kwarg):
    for i, df in enumerate(dflist):
        df.to_hdf(file_name_ptrn.format(i+1), 'df{:02d}'.format(i+1), **kwarg)
    return len(dflist)
```

then you can call it like this:

```
save_dflist_hdfs(dflist, r'd:/temp/data_{:02}.h5', format='t',
                 complib='blosc', complevel=5)
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks MaxU! Is HDF store more for super big files? Or do you use it whatever the file size is due to its flexibility and convenience?

Comment: @castor, glad i could help. I'm using HDF because it's very flexible and convenient, especially [its ability to query data conditionally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38401560/5741205), to compress files and because of its [speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python/37012035#37012035)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the code `a=+1`. You should write `a += 1` instead.